# How to extract multiple columns according to condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to this data analysis, I am currently working with a company's data. Where I have more than 100 columns worth of data. These columns are interrelated to each other, where the first four columns provide the description of the data so (id, domain, description, actual target). Rest of the other columns are just other numerical value that basically states the target value they reached for that day.

So, basically the question the company asked me to find is, which id have fluctuated the most and which id have failing to reach target.

I wanted to know, how i can properly execute the question, as its my very first time doing data analysis for a company.

What i did was firstly, i grouped the domain to see how many id's are associated with different domains.

Then I went about finding mean of every id in each domain (grouped). In finding the mean i can basically see if the id is failing to reach the target for that domain. Self explanatory, if most id's are failing to reach the target in specific domain, that means the domain/id is failing to reach the target.

```
df.groupby('Domain)['Id'].count() /*This tells me different domain with how many id's are there */
df[(df.Domain == 'Finance')].mean(axis = 1) /*Finance is just one of the domain that has different id's associated to it */
```

But what the problem i am facing is that i can extract the mean of each id in grouped domain, however I can't seem to open the id and target columns that is associated to those mean values. So i can compare if the mean value is reaching the target value. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a dataset similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'domain': ['Finance', 'RD', 'Finance', 'RD'], 'target': [34, 2, 41, 86]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    domain  target
0  Finance      34
1       RD       2
2  Finance      41
3       RD      86
```

Of course, you can use **groupby** to find statistical values of specific columns. For example,

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('domain')['target'].sum().reset_index()

    domain  target
0  Finance      75
1       RD      88
```

By using **mean()** or other statistical functions, you must be aware of your sample size which might affect your interpretation. For instance,

```
data = {'domain': ['Finance', 'RD', 'RD', 'RD'], 'target': [100, 2, 54, 86]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    domain  target
0  Finance     100
1       RD       2
2       RD      54
3       RD      86


df_grouped = df.groupby('domain')['target'].mean()

    domain      target
0  Finance  100.000000
1       RD   47.333333
```

**Data Visualization**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df_grouped.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess from your perspective your explanation is clear in terms of your scenario. But, i guess its not answering my question. I have added the photo of my table.

Comment: Now for that table if i do new df.groupby('Domain')['ID'].count(), it will sort my data according to my domain. After than if i do df[(df.iloc[:,2:].Domain=='Finance'].mean(axis=1), it will give me mean of the dates for the finance domain

Comment: But, i would like the output to display me the mean of the row, aswell as the target for the mean (so target for finance ID) aswell as the ID for the finance domain.

Comment: @krijan I strongly recommend you to display a sample of your data and an expected output in a tabular form or etc. in order to make everyone understand clearly.

Comment: Hello, I managed to find answer to my question and posted it up, please see my answer. :). Thank you very much for your assistance too, i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Hello I managed to find answer to this issue
So basically this is what I did

df["avg"] = df.iloc[:,3:].mean(axis = 1)

df[(df.Domain == 'Finance')].loc[:,['ID','Domain','Target','avg']]

Comment: This will basically print out the avg column as well as the ID, Domain, Target. By doing this, it became really easy for me to compare the target with the avg :)